# How to write variables in a file?

Tags: ruby

I have this code in Ruby which creates a file and sets two variables :

```
userId = 76
userkey = UtRzoP
configFile = File.new("file.txt", "w")
```

And I want to write the two variables on the file, but I don't know how to do that. I used this code to write a string content :

```
configFile.puts("id=userId\nkey=userKey")
```

But it doesn't work. Can you help me ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `write`:

```
userId = 76
userkey = "UtRzoP"
configFile = File.new("file.txt", "w")
configFile.write("id=#{userId}\nkey=#{userkey}")
configFile.close
```

As others in the comments point out, you can do the same with blocks:

```
File.open("file.txt", "w") { |f| f.write("id=#{userId}\nkey=#{userkey}") }
```

PS: `puts` puts a new line at the end of the string when written to a file. Personally, I favor `write` because it doesn't put that last new line in the end.

Comment: The problem was missing `#{...}`, not `write` vs. `puts`

Comment: Furthermore, you could show the OP how to improve the code using `File::open` with a block.